# How to Login in Web Application using REST APIs through JMETER

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying a Performance scenario where single user logs in to web application.
For that i am using Jmeter and REST-APIs

Here i have to call REST-APIs for that i have used "HTTP Request Defaults", I have created one thread group and added one "HTTP Request Default".

From APIs i have to pass two parameters:
1) User Name
2) Password

What would be the syntax of parameters in HTTP Request Defaults? or what sampler i should use for this?

I have one API link from which we can trigger those parameter, which will get applied on web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you'll need a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) configured to send the following header:

   - Name: `Content-Type`
   - Value: `application/json`

   Elsewise your request may not be processed as needed
2. The sampler you need to use is generic [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. The easiest way to provide JSON payload is to switch to `Body Data` tab and put your JSON there as below:

[image: JSON in HTTP Request]

3. Optionally you may with to use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) for correlation

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for a quick ramp-up on the RESTful web services testing domain.

Answer (score 0):

for ease of use

- In your Jmeter click on File, select Templates
- In the opened window/dialog, select "Building a SOAP web-service test plan"
- Click on Create.

It will open a test plan, which should give you a fare idea on how to achieve your scenario.

Hope this will help.